# Laravel 5 Dynamic Controller Routing

Tags: laravel, controller, routes

I have routing at Laravel 5.2 like this:

```
Route::group( [ 'prefix' => 'users/{hash}/addresses', 'as' => 'admin.addresses.' ], function () {
    Route::get( 'getdata', [ 'as' => 'getdata', 'uses' => 'AddressController@getData' ] );
    Route::get( 'create', [ 'as' => 'create', 'uses' => 'AddressController@create' ] );
    Route::post( 'create', [ 'as' => 'store', 'uses' => 'AddressController@store' ] );
} );
```

How to set my action controller name on my route group declaration?

it's suppose like this:

```
Route::group( [ 'prefix' => 'users/{hash}/addresses', 'as' => 'admin.addresses.', 'controller' => 'AddressController' ], function () {
    Route::get( 'getdata', [ 'as' => 'getdata', 'uses' => 'getData' ] );
    Route::get( 'create', [ 'as' => 'create', 'uses' => 'create' ] );
    Route::post( 'create', [ 'as' => 'store', 'uses' => 'store' ] );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use resource routes.

```
Route::resource('users/{hash}/addresses/admin.addresses', 'AddressController');
```

If you only need index and create you can specify it like this.

```
Route::resource('users/{hash}/addresses/admin.addresses', 'AddressController', ['only' => ['index', 'store']]);
```

Comment: How to set the alias name of the resource route? "as" => "admin.addresses.blabla"

Comment: I edit my answer. you want to add url path as resource parameter

Comment: If you have this route inside the group "users/{hash}/addresses" you only need to add "admin.addresses" as resource parameter